# Explain the Step by step execution of the recursion code to convert Decimal to Binary in Java

Tags: java, binary

So, this is the code to convert a Decimal number to Binary number using recursion in Java, the code works without any error. But I am confused how does the compiler execute this code, like I was solving it using paper, but I am not able to understand how the compiler takes it and generates the output.
When I was solving it on paper the solution did not make any sense to me. If anybody can tell me how it works, please. Have been sitting on the problem for more than 1 hour now.

I would be happy if somebody describes me the step by step execution of the code and arriving at the same output as the code.

Have used recursion like shown below.

```
public class RecursionPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("The converted number is " + dectoBin(7));
    }

private static int dectoBin(int n){
        if(n == 0 )
            return 0;
        else
            return  n % 2 + 10 * dectoBin(n/2);
    }
}
```

The output is as expected

The converted number is 111

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: so, have you tried following the flow?

Comment: Yes, I did. For example, I can understand how this code manually works

 ```private static int sum(int n){
        if(n == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return n % 10 + sum(n/10);
    }
```
But unable to understand the code I posted.

Comment: Function name should be `decimalToBinary` .

Comment: Lol, thanks for pointing out that.

Comment: "I can understand how this code manually works" ... "but unable to understand the code I posted". How can you both understand it and not understand it at the same time?

Comment: The code which I posted on the comment is different from what I posted on the question. @Stultuske

Comment: I asked you if you followed the flow. You said yes, and you said you understood it

Comment: Yes, I followed the flow, so in that case, shouldn't it return the sum, which is 3 but it returns 111.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step By Step Execution as follows. Hopefully you'll understand now .

```
1st call: dectoBin(7) =>  return  7 % 2 + 10 * dectoBin(7/2); => 1 + 10 * dectoBin(3);

2nd call: dectoBin(3) =>  return  3 % 2 + 10 * dectoBin(3/2); => 1 + 10 * dectoBin(1);

3rd call: dectoBin(1) =>  return  1 % 2 + 10 * dectoBin(1/2); => 1 + 10 * dectoBin(0);

4th call: dectoBin(0) =>  return  0; // base case
```

Evaluate all of these

```
 dectoBin(7);
 7 % 2 + 10 * dectoBin(3);
 7 % 2 + 10 * ( 3 % 2 + 10 * dectoBin(1) );
 7 % 2 + 10 * ( 3 % 2 + 10 * ( 1 % 2 + 10 * dectoBin(0) ) );
```

`dectoBin(0)` returns `0` So,

```
  7 % 2 + 10 * ( 3 % 2 + 10 * ( 1 % 2 + 10 * 0 ) );
  7 % 2 + 10 * ( 3 % 2 + 10 * ( 1 ) );
  7 % 2 + 10 * ( 11 );
  7 % 2 + 110;
  1 + 110;
  111;
```

Comment: Yea, this is what I was also thinking, so it's the addition of all the numbers. Thank you so much for a clear explanation.

Comment: @RookieProgrammer Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

1st Iteration:
7 % 2 + 10 * __

2nd Iteration
3 % 2 + 10 * __

3rd Iteration
1 % 2 + 10 * __

4th Iteration
return 0

3rd Iteration
1 % 2 + 10 * 0 = 1

2nd Iteration
3 % 2 + 10 * 1 = 1 + 10 = 11

1st Iteration:
7 % 2 + 10 * 11 = 1 + 110 = 111

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is a type of loop, if you have a problem to solve in your code (maybe converting a list to string in a special formatting) but that that problem has more instances of the same problem within it (That list has more lists inside of it that needed to be formatted in the same way).

In your example the loop will stop when the `decToBin()` method is given 0 as an argument. The loop basically goes on and keeps dividing the number by 2 until it gets to 0 or less and then it stops.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `7` to the method:

1. 7%2 + 10 * `dectoBin(7/2)`= 1 + 10* `dectoBin(3)`. Now n is 3.
2. (**dectoBin(3)**): 3%2 + 10* `dectoBin(3/2)` = 1 + 10 * `dectoBin(1)`. Now n is 1
3. (**dectoBin(1)**): 1%2 + 10* `dectoBin(1/2)` =  1+ 10 * `dectoBin(0)`. Now n is 0
4. (**dectoBin(0)**): return 0;

Going backwards: `1 + 10* (1 +10 *(1+10*0))=1+ 10*(1 + 10)= 1 +110 =111`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understood it.